# JSON int key issue data e2e (invalid character '1' looking for beginning of object key string)

Tags: json, integration-testing, aerospike, end-to-end, endly

My app uses aerospike to store Map in one of the bins,
I am use [endly](https://github.com/viant/endly/) for e2e testing, which uses JSON for data representation:

How do to populate datastore with with JSON  where key needs to be an int ?
Since json does not allowed int key I am getting the following error:  invalid character '1' looking for beginning of object key string

Here is my data workflow (invoked by regression workflow)

@data.yaml

```
defaults:
  datastore: db1
pipeline:
  register:
    action: dsunit:register
    config:
    driverName: aerospike
    descriptor: "tcp([host]:3000)/[namespace]"
    parameters:
      dbname: db1
      namespace: test
      host: 127.0.0.1
      port: 3000
      dateFormat: yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss
  prepare:
    data:
      action: nop
      init:
      - key = data.db.mydaaset
      - mydaaset = $AsTableRecords($key)
    setup:
      action: dsunit:prepare
      URL: regression/db1/data/
      data: $mydaaset
```

Here is my use case level data:

@mydaaset.json

```
[
  {
    "Table": "myDataset",
    "Value": [{
      "id": "$id",
      "created": "$timestamp.yesterday",
      "fc":{
                1191: "$timestamp.yesterday",
                1192: "$timestamp.now",
      }
    }],
   "AutoGenerate": {
      "id": "uuid.next"
    },
    "Key": "${tagId}_myDataset"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2):

In your example @mydaaset.json file is invalid JSON,  thus you getting

```
'invalid character '1' looking for beginning of object key string'
```

parsing error

In order to pre-seed your use case test data in aerospike with map[int]int bin you can use AsInt UDF

@mydaaset.json

```
[
  {
    "Table": "myDataset",
    "Value": [{
      "id": "$id",
      "created": "$timestamp.yesterday",
      "fc":{
                "$AsInt(1191)": "$timestamp.yesterday",
                "$AsInt(1192)": "$timestamp.now",
      }
    }],
   "AutoGenerate": {
      "id": "uuid.next"
    },
    "Key": "${tagId}_myDataset"
  }
]
```